# How to transform a vector in matrix according to following rules

Tags: python, numpy

I have a column vector y of length N containing a set of integers (1,2,3....K).
I want a matrix of size N x K of ones and zeros, as follows:

If the number in the vector y corresponds to the column index, the matrix has a one.
Otherwise, a zero.

Better with an example

```
 y = [0,1,2,1]
```

Expected output

```
M = [[1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 1]
     [0, 1, 0]]
```

How can I implement this in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [108]: M = np.zeros((4,3),int)                                                      
In [109]: M[np.arange(4), y] = 1                                                       
In [110]: M                                                                            
Out[110]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

This assigns 1 to elements specified by (i, y(i)).

```
In [111]: list(zip(np.arange(4), y))                                                   
Out[111]: [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
y = [0,1,2,1]
k = 3

arr = np.zeros((len(y),k))

for row, i in zip(arr, y):
    row[i]=1

print(arr)
```

**Without Using Numpy**

```py
y = [0,1,2,1]
k = 3

arr = [([0]*k).copy() for _ in range(len(y))]

for row, i in zip(arr, y):
    row[i]=1

print(arr)
```

Comment: he doesnt use numpy and it seems this is a raw program question to program by oneself instead of using ready-made functions

Comment: the question is tagged numpy so I assumed he/she wants to use numpy